# Rendering the UL of uiAutocomplete on another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

Typically the uiAutocomplete will generate something like

```
<ul>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to generate an element that the  will be positioned over
i.e.

```
<div class="new-autocomplete-base">
    <div class="custom-layer"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The idea is that the .custom-layer has some cool filter effects (i.e. glass effect ^_^)
renderMenu does not appear to be sufficient hence ui has already created the "base" already. Where can I intervene (where does it generate the ) so I can generate my "stack"?